# TypeError: createDebug.load is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing the following error while trying to serve my project built using AdonisJs.

Error:

```
    at setup (D:\NodeJsProjects\AdonisWallet\node_modules\knex\node_modules\debug\src\common.js:261:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJsProjects\AdonisWallet\node_modules\knex\node_modules\debug\src\node.js:236:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJsProjects\AdonisWallet\node_modules\knex\node_modules\debug\src\index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
```

This problem is caused by the following line of code. In this code, AddonModel is a lucid Model provided by adonisjs

```
      const ad= await AddonModule.findBy('name', addon_name)
```

I am not sure why is this happening. I have properly imported model using const AddonModule = use('App/Models/Addon')

Code seems like this

```
 await files.forEach(async (file) => {
      var addon_name=file
      const ad= await AddonModule.findBy('name', addon_name)
})
```

Comment: That looks like an internal problem in the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) module, which is pretty weird. Try reinstalling your dependencies?

Comment: @Bergi I deleted modules and reinstalled them yet making no difference.I am not sure why Module Call is causing this. because without module call it works fine.